# Can't find logic behind png file sizes

Tags: compression, png

I'm saving a large number of small png files for use in a game on a phone, so space is at a premium.

I'm trying to figure out the logic behind the file sizes so I can save things most efficiently, but even after using pngcrush the sizes are totally inconsistent.

I saved a 1x1 image and it takes 3kb. I have another 23x21 image which takes only 2kb. I have two images which are almost the same size, but one takes 6kb and the other takes 13kb. I doubled the image height and copied one image into the empty space of the other and saved that. The combined image is only 11kb!

Why is a 1x1 image larger than a 23x21 image? Why can I combine a 13kb image and a 6kb image and get an 11kb image?

Here are the images I'm talking about (there's a 1x1 pixel in between the 1st and second images. It's difficult to see, so I'll just give the URL: http://g42.org/temp/png/1x1.png):

[example http://g42.org/temp/png/hat.png](http://g42.org/temp/png/hat.png)
 [example http://g42.org/temp/png/1x1.png](http://g42.org/temp/png/1x1.png)
 [example http://g42.org/temp/png/helmet1.png](http://g42.org/temp/png/helmet1.png)
 [example http://g42.org/temp/png/helmet2.png](http://g42.org/temp/png/helmet2.png)
 [example http://g42.org/temp/png/helmet1_2.png](http://g42.org/temp/png/helmet1_2.png)

Comment: How are you creating the .png files?  Is there non-image meta-data in the png files?

Comment: I'm using Photoshop. I didn't intentionally put metadata in the files, but I would have thought that using pngcrush would have removed it from them if it was there.

Comment: 1x1 image? That shouldn't use more than 300 bytes..

Comment: `xxd 1x1.png > 1x1.xxd` (a hexdump) shows the 1x1 image has a Photoshop [ICC profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile) in it. If you can tell Photoshop to use the sRGB color profile, that might cut down on the size. (At least that's what GIMP used to create a 122 byte version).

Comment: Ok, that solves the mystery of the 1x1. I went to assign profile and set "Don't Color Manage This Document". The file saved as 140 bytes. I'm not sure what impact that would have though. I tried it with the other images. It seems to save about 2 to 3kb per image. It still doesn't explain the size reduction of the combined image though. The new combined image is 7.7kb. The originals are 5kb and 11kb. The combined image is still smaller even without the color profile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a compression thing, the problem with the 1x1 image is that it has metadata (added by Photoshop, it seems), a color profile (iCCP chunk). If you look inside the binary, its' the data between the strings "iCCP" and "IDAT", it could be removed and you get a 69 bytes file.
If you reopen and save the file most image viewers (xnview), or use pngcrush, you can strip that chunk. : See it here : [image]  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmOdA.png

And regarding the helmet images: besides other informational chunks (imageReady ads some informational text, as you can see), the difference is due to different formats: the two-helmets is a paletted image (8bits per pixel), the single helmet is a RGB with alpha (32bits per pixel)

Answer (score 1):

PNG compression is based on the same algorithm as zlib and is highly sensitive to the data that is being compressed so you won't see a consistent relationship between image size and file size.  In the case of the combined image, it is still bigger than the smaller image and given the similarity of the two halves of the image, the compressor was probably able to reuse a lot of the Huffman tree.  I don't know enough about the algorithm to say for certain how it ended up smaller than the other half.

As long as you are not seeing oddities like the 1x1 image, which you seem to have figured out in the comments, I don't think this will make a lot of sense without extensive study of image compression.

Comment: It makes sense that taking a 5kb image and combining it with an 11kb image would end up with a file smaller than 16kb. I'm trying to figure out why you can take those two files and end up with a file that's 7kb (smaller than the 11kb image). Is it really reasonable that adding more data can make compression more efficient? It does appear that the color is slightly different in the combined image. That probably plays a part in the mystery.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great utility called pngcrush

http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/

Compressing to PNG is a rather difficult task - there are lost of assumptions and strategies to try - do we create a palette, or are we better off without it?

PNGcrush essentially bruteforces 100+ different compression strategies, while at the same time trimming useless tags and sections.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original question, I'm already using pngcrush. (Actually, I just realized I hadn't done it for the last combined image. I crushed it and it went down to 10 which makes even less sense!)

Answer (score 0):

PNG has several sub-formats: 24-bit with or without alpha, 8-bit (includes alpha), grayscale, etc. which use different amount of bytes per pixel and have different "compressibility".

Plus PNG supports several compression tricks (filters and gzip settings) which affect how well image data is compressed.

On top of that PNG can contain metadata, which sometimes can be pretty large, like some embedded color profiles.

- [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com) converts images to the most space-efficient PNG8+alpha variant.
- [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com) removes junk metadata and finds best compression parameters.

With a combination of those two your images can be reduced by 30-50%.